# How to Convert as400 Spooled file to excel (XLS) file

Tags: java, excel, ibm-midrange, jt400

I'm new to as400 Java development (JT400).I'm get spooled file list and read it normal text. now i want to convert it to excel (XLS) file. I'm Trying to convert AS400 spooled file to excel(XLS) file using Java.but im faild. Anyone know how to do it ? can i convert directly it from as400 ? anyone know how to convert this spooled file (or this text file) to excel file using Java ?

thanks in advance!

#### MY one of spooled file like this :

```
5722WDS V5R3M0  030905 RN        IBM ILE RPG             XXXXXXXXX/XXXX           SSSS        10/01/11 06:19:46        Page      1


Command  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   CRTBNDRPG

Issued by  . . . . . . . . . . :     XXXXXXXXX

Program  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   CUSR

Library  . . . . . . . . . . . :     XXXXXXXXX

Text 'description' . . . . . . . :   *SRCMBRTXT


Source Member  . . . . . . . . . :   CUSR

Source File  . . . . . . . . . . :   XXXXXXXXX

Library  . . . . . . . . . . . :     XXXXXXXXX

CCSID  . . . . . . . . . . . . :     273

Text 'description' . . . . . . . :

Last Change  . . . . . . . . . . :   10/01/11  06:19:41


Generation severity level  . . . :   10

Default activation group . . . . :   *YES

Compiler options . . . . . . . . :   *XREF      *GEN       *NOSECLVL  *SHOWCPY

                                   *EXPDDS    *EXT       *NOSHOWSKP *NOSRCSTMT

                                   *DEBUGIO   *NOEVENTF

Debugging views  . . . . . . . . :   *SOURCE

Output . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *PRINT

Optimization level . . . . . . . :   *NONE

Source listing indentation . . . :   *NONE

Type conversion options  . . . . :   *NONE

Sort sequence  . . . . . . . . . :   *HEX

Language identifier  . . . . . . :   *JOBRUN

Replace program  . . . . . . . . :   *YES

User profile . . . . . . . . . . :   *USER

Authority  . . . . . . . . . . . :   *LIBCRTAUT

Truncate numeric . . . . . . . . :   *YES

Fix numeric  . . . . . . . . . . :   *NONE

Target release . . . . . . . . . :   *CURRENT

Allow null values  . . . . . . . :   *NO

Define condition names . . . . . :   *NONE

Enable performance collection  . :   *PEP

Profiling data . . . . . . . . . :   *NOCOL

Licensed Internal Code options . :

Generate program interface . . . :   *NO

Include directory  . . . . . . . :

Preprocessor options . . . . . . :   *NONE

5722WDS V5R3M0  030905 RN        IBM ILE RPG             XXXXXXXXX/XXXX           SSSS       10/01/11 06:19:46        Page      2


Line   <---------------------- Source Specifications ----------------------------><----     Comments ----> Do  Page  Change Src Seq

Number  ....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+....8....+....9....+...10 Num Line  Date   Id  Number


                      S o u r c e   L i s t i n g


 1                                                                                                             110917     000100



 2 FCUS00D    CF   E             WORKSTN                                                                     110917     000200

    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

    *                               RPG name         External name                               *

    * File name. . . . . . . . . :  CUS00D           XXXXXXXXX/SSSSSS                            *

    * Record format(s) . . . . . :  RECORD           RECORD                                      *

    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

 3 FCUSMAS01  UF A E             DISK                                                                        110917     000300

 4                                                                                                           110917     000400

 5  /Free                                                                                                    110917     000500

 6                                                                                                           110917     000600

    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

    *                               RPG name         External name                               *

    * File name. . . . . . . . . :  CUSMAS01         XXXXXXXXX/SSSSSS                          *

    * Record format(s) . . . . . :  CUSREC           CUSREC                                      *

    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*



 7=IRECORD                                                                                                             1000001

    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*                     1

    * RPG record format  . . . . :  RECORD                                                       *                     1

    * External format  . . . . . :  RECORD : XXXXXXXXX/SSSSSS                                   *                     1

    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*                     1

 8=I                             N    1    1  *IN03                                                                    1000002

 9=I                             N    2    2  *IN06                                                                    1000003

10=I                             S    3    8 0$CUSID                                                                   1000004

11=I                             A    9   33  $CUSNAME                                                                 1000005

12=I                             A   34   58  $CUSADD1                                                                 1000006

13=I                             A   59   83  $CUSADD2                                                                 1000007

14=I                             A   84  108  $CUSADD3                                                                 1000008

15=I                             S  109  118 0$TELNO                                                                   1000009

16=I                             S  119  133 3$CRDLMT                                                                  1000010

17=ICUSREC                                                                                                             2000001

    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*                     2

    * RPG record format  . . . . :  CUSREC                                                       *                     2

    * External format  . . . . . :  CUSREC : XXXXXXXXX/SSSSSS                                  *                     2

    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*                     2

18=I                             P    1    4 0CUSID                                                                    2000002

19=I                             A    5   29  CUSNAME                                                                  2000003

20=I                             A   30   54  CUSADD1                                                                  2000004

21=I                             A   55   79  CUSADD2                                                                  2000005

22=I                             A   80  104  CUSADD3                                                                  2000006

23=I                             S  105  114 0TELNO                                                                    2000007

24=I                             S  115  129 2CRDLMT                                                                   2000008



25    Exfmt record;                                                                                          110917     000700

26     Dow Not *IN03;                                                                              B01       110924     000800

27       If $CUSID <> *Zeros;                                                                      B02       111001     000801

28        Chain (CUSID) CUSREC;                                                                     02       111001     000802

29          If %Found(CUSMAS01);                                                                   B03       111001     000803
```

### ...etc

Comment: I would take a look at the Apache POI library.  It is meant to handle Microsoft format, including Excel.  If you want to handle it yourself, you can also just write it out as a straight CSV file (Comma Separated Values), which Excel will also open.

Comment: I dont know about CSV file. can you tell me about CSV file. How to write CSV file. Thank you so much for help :)

Comment: CSV file = comma-separated values.  Google has details.

Comment: A CSV file is simply a file where each "row" is delimited by a carriage return, and each "value" is delimited by a comma.  I believe there are a few Java libraries out there that can aid in CSV creation, but it's easy enough just to write it out.  The downside of a CSV is that it's text-only, so you can't do formulas or any formatting (bold, italics, etc) like you can in an XLS (Excel) file.  But, it's the most basic format you can output to get a matrix of stuff out.

Comment: my spooled files are not same. then i have to write deferent CSV files. its too hard :(

Comment: Are all of your spooled files going to be source members? If so, what are you really trying to accomplish by converting them all into Excel files?

Comment: Are your spool files generated by the operating system or other system supplied software? This will cause release dependencies. If you scan the spool file to extract data, what are you going to do when IBM changes how they present the report? Please explain in more detail what it is that you are trying to accomplish, and we can help you avoid design issues that can cause you a out of grief.

Comment: Why would you want to convert a compile listing to an Excel spreadsheet?  (Perhaps it was supposed to be XML?)

Answer (score 3):

There are two libraries that support direct conversion to Excel: [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) and [jExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/).

In addition [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) is a higher level reporting library that supports exporting to Excel in addition to PDF, etc.

The real issue is how do you expect to map a free flowing format such as your example to a row and column format like Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spooled file like

```
 DATE TIME NAME
 12345678901234
```

You can save to file your spool.
The way I use (hope it helps)...
tipically it has only one field and you need to generate the various fields by position.
you can produce by query a file like substr(field, 1, 4) for date, substr(field, 6, 4) for time and so on.
With java I prefer to use Apache POI, like this..

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
```

..........................

```
wbk=new SXSSFWorkbook(500);
sheet=vbk.createSheet("book 1");
try{
    Row rowhead=sheet.createRow(0);
    rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Hello");
            ...
            <Here you fill the Excel with the resultset of your query
            to the AS400 file using JT400>
            ...
    FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(excelPath);
    wbk.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
}catch(Exception e){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest for me is a command similar to this:

```
qsh cmd('touch -C 1252 mysplftxt.spl && catsplf -j 987654/myuser/myjob  mysplf 1 >mysplftxt.spl' )
```

The [**Qshell catsplf utility**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/rzahz/rzahzcatsplf.htm) puts a spooled file into STDOUT. In the example above, it's redirected to a streamfile named `mysplftxt.spl` that has no path, so it goes into the current directory. Since my current directory is mapped to a network drive in my PC, I can then simply open the file in LibreOffice Calc (no need for Excel here).

That's all there is to it.

Well, technically, there is more to it because I created a command I've named CATSPLF that accepts job name, spoolfile name and number, etc., and constructs the Qshell CMD() string for me. That makes it a lot easier to make the request in a number ways like as a registered user function for the WRKSPLF command and elsewhere.

Naturally, there is no definition of "cells" in the spreadsheet when I do that. That needs to be done manually when I open the file. If "cells" are needed regularly, there are two general options other than manual: start writing programs to do it or buy a product.

But I rarely see any point in opening a spooled file in Excel (or in Calc or any other spreadsheet program). I wouldn't try similarly to open a spooled file from the Windows spooler (which would be a real nightmare), and I've never heard of anyone else trying to do it either; so I can't figure out why people want to do it so often in the AS/400 line. There are almost always far better ways to get data into a spreadsheet.